# read json and insert in list view

Tags: android, json, listview

i want to read from json on url address to list view but there is noting to show.
this is my code.
main activity.

```
    package customlistviewvolley;

import com.example.customlistviewvolley.R;

/*import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;*/
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;

import customlistviewvolleyadater.CustomListAdapter;
import customlistviewvolleyapp.AppController;
import customlistviewvolleymodel.App;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://192.168.1.5/public_html/android/new.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<App> appList = new ArrayList<App>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, appList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // changing action bar color
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest appReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                App app = new App();
                                app.setAppTitle(obj.getString("app_title"));
                                app.setAppImageUrl(obj.getString("app_image"));
                                app.setRatingBar(((Number) obj.get("app_rating"))
                                        .doubleValue());
                                app.setAppCreator(obj.getString("app_creator"));

                                app.setAppCase(obj.getString("app_case"));


                                // adding app to app array
                                appList.add(app);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hidePDialog();

                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(appReq);
    }


        /* JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
         JSONArray m_jArry = obj1.getJSONArray("apps");
         //ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> formList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // HashMap<String, String> m_li;

         for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) {
                try {

                    JSONObject obj = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);
                    App app = new App();
                    app.setAppTitle(obj.getString("app_title"));
                    app.setAppImageUrl(obj.getString("app_image"));
                    app.setRatingBar(((Number) obj.get("rating_bar"))
                            .doubleValue());
                    app.setAppCreator(obj.getString("app_creator"));

                    app.setAppCase(obj.getString("app_case"));


                    // adding movie to movies array
                    appList.add(app);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            //Same way for other value...
           }*/

        /*public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
            String json = null;
            try {

                InputStream is = getAssets().open("jsonfile.json");

                int size = is.available();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

                is.read(buffer);

                is.close();

                json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            return json;

        }   */

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }





}
```

custom adapter.

```
    package customlistviewvolleyadater;

import com.example.customlistviewvolley.R;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import customlistviewvolleyapp.AppController;
import customlistviewvolleymodel.App;

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<App> appItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<App> appItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.appItems = appItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return appItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return appItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_new_free, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView appImage = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.app_image);
        TextView appTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_title);
        TextView appCase = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_case);
        TextView appCreator = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_creator);
        RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_rating_bar);

        // getting app data for the row
        App app = appItems.get(position);

        // app image
        appImage.setImageUrl(app.getAppImageUrl(), imageLoader);

        // title
        appTitle.setText(app.getAppTitle());

        // app creator
        appCreator.setText( app.getAppCreator());

        // appCase
        appCase.setText(app.getAppCase());

        // rating bar
        ratingBar.setNumStars((int) app.getRatingBar());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

app controller.

```
    package customlistviewvolleyapp;

import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import customlistviewvolleyutil.LruBitmapCache;

public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

app.

```
    package customlistviewvolleymodel;



public class App {
    private String appTitle, appImageUrl, appCreator;

    private double ratingBar;
    private String appCase;

    public App() {
    }

    public App(String appName, String appImageUrl, String appCreator, double ratingBar,
            String appCase) {
        this.appTitle = appName;
        this.appImageUrl = appImageUrl;
        this.appCreator = appCreator;
        this.ratingBar = ratingBar;
        this.appCase = appCase;
    }

    public String getAppTitle() {
        return appTitle;
    }

    public void setAppTitle(String name) {
        this.appTitle = name;
    }

    public String getAppImageUrl() {
        return appImageUrl;
    }

    public void setAppImageUrl(String appImageUrl) {
        this.appImageUrl = appImageUrl;
    }




    public String getAppCreator() {
        return appCreator;
    }

    public void setAppCreator(String appCreator) {
        this.appCreator = appCreator;
    }

    public double getRatingBar() {
        return ratingBar;
    }

    public void setRatingBar(double ratingBar) {
        this.ratingBar = ratingBar;
    }

    public String getAppCase() {
        return appCase;
    }

    public void setAppCase(String appCase) {
        this.appCase = appCase;
    }

}
```

here is my cache code .

```
`   `package customlistviewvolleyutil;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageCache;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;

public class LruBitmapCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements
        ImageCache {
    public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        return cacheSize;
    }

    public LruBitmapCache() {
        this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
    }

    public LruBitmapCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
        super(sizeInKiloBytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap);
    }
}
```

my main activity xml .

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my rows here .

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <!-- Thumbnail Image -->

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

     <!-- App(movie) Title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/app_image"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/app_image"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
     <!-- App Creator -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_creator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_image"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/app_image"
        android:textSize="@dimen/creator"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />



    <!-- Type Free or NotFree or Installed -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_case"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="@color/year"
        android:textSize="@dimen/type" />

    <!-- Rating Bar -->
    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/app_rating_bar"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/app_image"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_creator"
        android:stepSize="0.5" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

plz help me to fix it.

Comment: you dont read write your whole app to fix this problem , its easy

Comment: you try fetch data from local server , there many problem happen in this point , make sure your destination is reachable

Comment: There is way too much code in the question. It cannot possibly all be relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should access localhost sites in such a way:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyTestPage.html
```

Read this to get further information:

http://www.androidref.com//index.html#LocalBrowser

Comment: i want to access the json file on another computer in local network not in my local hodt